# How to escape quotes of array keys inside background-image url?

Tags: php, html, css

This is my code :

```
echo  '<div class="banner" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_Array["sizes"]["large"]; ?>);">';
```

If I do

```
  echo  $img_Array["sizes"]["large"];
```

I get correct image path but when I use it inside `background-image` it does not worked for me.

When I used inspect element it displayed:

```
 element.style {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $img_Array[;
    }
```

That means it needs to escape quotes(") of sizes , i tried to use /" but didnt work .

Any help would be appreciated . Thank you .

Comment: uh... don't `echo` inside `echo`, there is no need...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo  '<div class="banner" style="background-image: url(' . $img_Array["sizes"]["large"] . ' );">';
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aju John , it helped alot . echo inside echo should be avoided .

Answer (score 0):

When you echo, you are already in PHP. No need to use `<?php` again.

```
echo  '<div class="banner" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_Array["sizes"]["large"]; ?>);">';
```

Change it to:

```
echo  '<div class="banner" style="background-image: url(' . $img_Array["sizes"]["large"] . ');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've tried to nest PHP code blocks. There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Echo the entire HTML code from the PHP block:

   ```
   <?php
   echo '<div class="banner" style="background-image: url('
        . $img_Array["sizes"]["large"] . ');">';`
   ?>
   ```
2. Echo just the URL with a PHP block nested in HTML:

   ```
   <div class="banner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $img_Array["sizes"]["large"]; ?>');">
   ```